# How to get same entity from em.find method?

Tags: java, jpa

How to get same entity from `em.find` method?

```
Address address=em.find(Address.class,1);
System.out.println("Name of Address: "+address.getAddressName);   // Chinnur
address.setAddressName("Russia");
Address address1=em.find(Address.class,address.getAddressId());
System.out.println("Name of Address: "+address1.getAddressName); //?????????
```

i need `address1.getAddressName` is "chinnur",

but i got  `address1.getAddressName` is "Russia"

i need brief explanation please help me.

Comment: you fetch the entity, you modify it, modified copy is stored in hibernate TX cache (since the entity you fetched is attached to the EM). you fetch the entity again - you get the modified copy from the cache. all working as designed. the minute you commit the TX the values in the modified entoty will be written out to the DB

Comment: Radai Thanks for information, how can i get address1.getAddressName is "chinnur"

Answer (score 0):

Modified entity is stored in  transaction `cache`,When you want to retrieve again the cached results is showing